# Weird Integration Anomaly: $\ln x = \ln \pi x$

Tags: integration

While doing a sum, I noticed that $$\ln x=\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\int \frac{\pi}{\pi x}dx=\ln \pi x$$
if we take $\pi x$ as another variable $u$.

Why is such a thing happening, how does is it consistent with definition of the $\ln$ function, and does it make a physical sense, as in would this be consistent with the way we define the area by integration?

Comment: you forgot $+C$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant.

It should be

$$\ln x + C = \int \frac 1x \, dx$$

and on the other side, it should be

$$\int \frac{\pi}{\pi x}\, dx = \ln (\pi x) + \text{constant} = \ln \pi + \ln (x) + \text{constant} = \ln (x) + C$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\frac{d}{dx}\log kx=\frac1{kx}\cdot k=\frac1x.$$

But at the same time, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\log kx=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log k+\log x\right).$$

Think about the constant of integration and how it would be absorbed by means of laws of logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

Your first equality is not correct. You have to write that for $ x>0$,

$$\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^x\frac{\pi dt}{\pi t}=$$
$$\int_{\pi}^{\pi x}\frac{du}{u}=\ln(\pi x)-\ln(\pi)=\ln(x)$$

with the substitution $u =\pi t$.
So, when things are well defined, there is no anomaly.

Comment: Would probably serve better as a comment (or an edit, even).

Comment: @AndrewChin What makes you say that? This _is_ answer. The OP made a subtle error in their reasoning, and asks why they reach an inconsistent conclusion. This post explains the error that was made and shows that the objects at hand are consistent. What else do you expect for an answer?

Comment: Look at the edit history and the timestamp of my comment, I guess.